# Transparent UI (+UIManager) artifacts

Tags: java, swing, transparent, uimanager, uidefaults

I've got an application which draws a `background image` on a `panel`, but to achieve the optimal UI, I need to set `Component` backgrounds `Transparent`:

I made every component transparent by using the UI Manager:
`uimanager.put(Button, background(new color(0, 0, 0, 0);` <- something like that, this works perfectly, except..

`onMouseOver` the `component` redraws itself (I guess) and causes Artifacts.. How can I avoid this in the `UIManager`?

(I created a class: `uidefaults.java` with all the `UIManager` settings)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)  demonstrated your issue(s) with `Transparency` and `UIManager`, otherwise you have to waiting for some of psychics that will post you correct answer

Comment: Okay, Ill do this when I get home, Im currently at work

Comment: Also, a screenshot of the artifacts might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that is pretty simple - DO NOT use transparent background colors with components (any JComponent ancestor to be exact) that are OPAQUE.

To remove component background you don't need to set transparent color - just use this method:

```
component.setOpaque ( false );
```

This will hide component background and will also change component repaint strategy so it won't create any artifacts on repaint calls.

Also, if you still want to have semi-transparent background behind your component you can override paintComponent method like this:

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel ( "Transparent background" )
    {
        protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
        {
            g.setColor ( getBackground () );
            g.fillRect ( 0, 0, getWidth (), getHeight () );
            super.paintComponent ( g );
        }
    };
    label.setOpaque ( false );
    label.setBackground ( new Color ( 255, 0, 0, 128 ) );
```

This will force label to hide its default background and also paint your own background (that depends on component's background property).

Comment: Is it thát simple? I'll let you know in about an hour when I get home! Thanks

Comment: Yes, its that simple. And by the way - don't use UIManager unless you want to change any properties globally (they will affect all comonents of the specific kind). For example in your code all buttons created/updated after you have set "Button.background" will use that background. If you want to modify single button instance - call its methods instead (setBackground in this case).